# Find $ f \circ f $ for the function $\lbrace f: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2 \: \vert \: f(x,y)=(-y,x) \rbrace$

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, functions

Find $f\circ f$ for the function $\lbrace f:\mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}^2 \:\vert\: f(x,y)=(-y,x)\rbrace$

I'm not really sure how to go about solving this, but here's what I have so far.

I know that if $f(x,y)=(-y,x)$, then $f(x)$ is its inverse reflected about the y-axis. If this is the case then $ f \circ f $ = $f^{-1}(-f^{-1}(-x))$.

The question is asking me to express $f \circ f$ in terms of its $x$ and $y$ components. Specifically, if $f\circ f  = f_2(x,y)$, then $f_2(x,y)=(?,?)$.

I don't really understand how I can express it like that, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Nice code! I usually used `left\{` and `\right`, but `\lbrace` and `\rbrace` are a discovery for me. I think there is no difference in the output. Where have you heard of this "commands"? This is excellent because my $N$ button on the keyboard doesn't work anymore.

Comment: @ms._VerkhovtsevaKatya Thank you! Yeah there is no difference in the output, and I found this command through a tutorial [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/tex_commands/index.htm) , they have a list of commands from a-z. Glad I could help though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $f(x,y)=(-y,x)$, $f\bigl(f(x,y)\bigr)=f(-y,x)=(-x,-y)$.